# Would a plane restricted to the first octant be a closed surface?

Tags: general-topology, multivariable-calculus

Take, for example: $3x + y + 2z = 6$.

Parameterized as: $ui +  (6 -3u - 2v)j + vk$
restricted to the first octant

Answer (score 1):

No, everywhere it meets $x=0$, $y=0$, or $z=0$, is a boundary point.

One way to see this: in a manifold $M$ with boundary, $x\in M$ is a boundary point if and only if $x$ has a neighborhood $U$ such that $U\setminus \{x\}$ is contractible.  But in your example, $M\setminus \{x\}$ is convex, hence contractible, for any corner point of $M$.

Answer (score 0):

A plane is closed.  A half-space is closed.  Finite intersections of closed sets are closed.  So as a subset of $\Bbb R^3$  it is closed.  If your definition of a closed surface is as in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surface#Closed_surfaces), a surface that is compact and without boundary, it is neither.  It is not compact because it extends to infinity, and it has a boundary.
,

Comment: "Closed surface" usually means something different than "surface that is closed as a subset of $\mathbb{R}^3$" though.